# Can we use ember-cli purely as a front end like we are using javascript and jquery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ember.js, ember-cli

Can we use ember-cli purely as a front end like we are using java-script and j query.I want to add reference of ember-cli in my .net project and use it just for validation.is it possible?any suggestion can be appreciated.

Comment: ember creates its own ember object. So even if you want to place ember validations in place you would require to use ember properties in the project. Normal Javascript objects will not be considered by Ember for validation.

Comment: should I use ember without node.js, with any back-end language like C#.net mvc

Comment: you can use any backend language you prefer. From my experience, Ember works great with Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember is only a fronted framework, so the only way to use ember is only for your frontend. Then you communicate with your backend by an API. You backend can be anything, from .NET, Java, Rails, Django, Node, or anything else.

But ember has its own build pipeline: `ember-cli`. This is not meant for use on your production server, but you *should* use it for development.

This way you develop your backend in .NET and VisualStudio, and your frontend separated with any editor and ember-cli. When you build your ember app for production you will end with a single `html` file, two `.js` files and a `.css` file that you can include in your IIS.

However you can use ember without `ember-cli` as a simple JS framework, but this is *not* recommended, since you would create your own build pipeline and can't use ember addons directly.